# Populate jQuery autoscroll plugin with data using ajax; Template function never fired

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to use a jQuery plugin called *[autoscroll](http://msjolund.github.com/autobrowse/twitterdemo.html)* to show comments on my site. However I am struggling to pull the comments from my database using AJAX, and the `template` function is never called.

```
$(".Reviews").autobrowse({
    url: function (offset) {
        //return Healthimized.Services.ClientUserServices.LoadClientUserReviews(1, LoadCustomerToSelectOption, ErrorHandler, onTimeOut)
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'Services/ClientUserServices.asmx/GetAllSpecialities',
            //data: parameters,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            //data: { fromDate: new Date(), toDate: new Date(), clientUserId:1},
            //data: "{'fromDate':'" + startFrom + "','toDate':'" + endTo + "','clientUserId':'" + doctorId + "'}",
            dataType: "json",
            //data: 'fromDate=' + new Date() + '&toDate=' + new Date() + '&clientUserId='+1,
            success: function (msg) {
                return "http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/ParisHilton.json?count=10&page=OFFSET&callback=?".replace(/OFFSET/, 1+Math.round(offset/10));
            },
            error: function (e) {
                $(divToBeWorkedOn).html("Unavailable");
            }
        });
    },
    template: function (response) {
        var markup='';
        for (var i=0; i<response.length; i++) {
            markup+='<div style="background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);margin: 2% 2% 2% 2%;border-radius: 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em;"><table>';
            markup += '<tr><td>';
            markup += '<img src="' + response[i].user.profile_image_url + '" /></td>';
            markup += '<td style="margin-top:-15px">'+response[i].text+'</td>';
            markup += '</tr></table></div>';
        }
        return markup;
    },
    itemsReturned: function (response) { return response.length; },
    max: 100,
    loader: '<div class="loader"></div>',
    sensitivity: 100,
    finished: function () { $(this).append('<p style="text-align:center"><b>No More Reviews to show</b></p>') }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code looks like a mix of disconnected pieces of code. In the second place, this plugin suited to work with RESTful services where parameters sends via query string as to call ASP.NET web service method you must to pass parameters via ajax request `data` object. Also, ASP.NET wraps ajax request response in JSON object, where actual response data stored in the `d` property.

Based on all these facts, you need to change plugin code a bit to use it with ASP.NET web service methods. To do this change this piece of plugin code:

```
if (options.postData)
{
    var data = null;
    if (typeof options.postData == "function")
    {
        data = options.postData();
    }
    else
    {
        data = options.postData;
    }

    jQuery.post(options.url(currentOffset), data, ajaxCallback, "json").error(options.onError);
}
else
{
    jQuery.getJSON(options.url(currentOffset), ajaxCallback).error(options.onError);
}
```

Changed code:

```
if (options.postData) {
    var data = null;
    if (typeof options.postData == "function") {
        data = options.postData(currentOffset);
    }
    else {
        data = options.postData;
    }

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: options.url(),
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: data,
        success: ajaxCallback,
        error: options.onError
    });
}
else {
    jQuery.getJSON(options.url(currentOffset), ajaxCallback).error(options.onError);
}
```

Lets consider that you have web service code as below:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class ClientUserServices : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public string[] GetAllSpecialities(int index)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 20).Select(id => Guid.NewGuid().ToString()).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Then you can utilize the `GetAllSpecialities` method with following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
          $("#Reviews").autobrowse({
               url : '<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/Services/ClientUserServices.asmx/GetAllSpecialities") %>',
               postData: function (index) {
                    return "{ 'index' :" + index + "}";
               },
               template: function (response) {
                    response = response.d;
                    var markup = '';
                    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                         markup += "<div>" + response[i] + "</div>";
                    }
                    return markup;
               },
               itemsReturned: function (response) {
                    return response.d.length;
               },
               offset: 0,
               max: 10000,
               useCache: true,
               expiration: 1,
               onError: function (error) {
               }
          });
     });
</script>

<div id="Reviews">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. i have changed the plugin js code to as you have mentioned and updated my script too to call the service according to your given example now there is no call to web service any more. Web Service is not being called now. what is wrong now? Thanks.